# Let $A$ be symmetric and positive definite. Suppose $A=LL^T$ is its Cholesky decomposition. Prove that $||A||_2=||L||_2^2$.

Tags: symmetric-matrices, numerical-calculus, matrix-norms, cholesky-decomposition

> Let $A$ be symmetric and positive definite. Suppose $A=LL^T$ is its Cholesky decomposition. Prove that $||A||_2=||L||_2^2$.

This is an exercise in my Numerical Analysis book. The offcial hint to this problem says:

> $||L||_2^2=\rho(L^TL)$

Following the hint, I can only show that $||L^T||_2^2=\rho(LL^T)=\rho(A)=||A||_2$. If the original proposition is true, then it is necessary $||L||_2=||L^T||_2$ for all nonsingular lower triangular $L$. But I don't think this is always true. Is there a typo in the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's true. **Hint:** $\|L\|=\max_{\x\|=\|y\|=1}|\langle x,\,Ly\rangle|$.

Comment: @Berci So $||B||_2=||B^T||_2$ for any matrix $B$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.